# No div with content is present in kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I'm trying to stylize a grid that my coworker is putting together.  It's getting created like this (Note: I deleted some of the columns that are bound to save some space):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<LibraryDetailViewModel>()
          .Name("myGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(l => l.LibraryId).Title("Library").ClientTemplate("\\#= LibraryPrepName \\#").EditorTemplateName("LibraryPrepsDropDownList");
                  columns.Bound(l => l.ModifiedOn).Title("Last Updated").ClientTemplate("\\#=ModifiedLabel\\# ").Width("20%"); 
                  columns.Command(command => {
                                         command.Edit();
                                         command.Destroy();
                                     }).Width(175);
              })

          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .PageSize(20)
                                        .ServerOperation(true)
                                        .Read(read => read.Url("api/source/#=Id#/libraries"))
                                        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("ModifiedOn").Descending())
                                        .Model(model =>
                                        {
                                            model.Id(l => l.Id);
                                            model.Field(l => l.ModifiedOn).Editable(false);
                                            model.Field(l => l.LibraryPrepId).Editable(true);
                                        })
          )
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .ToClientTemplate()
          )
```

So the kendo grid gets rendered properly when I look at it.  However, there is no `kendo-grid-content` div for the actual content of the grid.  I'm not sure why.  In other pages of our site, where the grid is rendered client side, not using the MVC syntax (this one is rendered server side), they all have a div with a class of `kendo-grid-content` that we use to stylize the grid.  This one does not have it.  Anyone have ideas why?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `k-grid-content` div is used if the grid is `scrollable`.

The default value for `scrollable` using the JavaScript API is `true` see also [in the documentation.](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-scrollable)

But the ASP.NET MVC wrappers uses the default value `false` for `scrollable` so you need configure your grid with the `Scrollable()` method:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<LibraryDetailViewModel>()
          .Name("myGrid")
          //..
          .Scrollable()
          .ToClientTemplate()
          )
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  But I'm guessing if my grid is using the Pagination feature, then scrollable wouldn't work well with it right?  Thanks!

Comment: The scrolling only displays a scrollbar when the total row height (or width) exceeds the grid height (or width). So it should work with the paging. But myself haven't tried it...

Comment: how would I know that it's the scrollable value that is using k-grid-content.  I don't see that on the page you referred.

Comment: It is not documented. I've read throguh the source code of the grid for this information. I've only found [this reference](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/grid/walkthrough) in the documentation but this also does not mention the purpose of the class